# Can I add properties to my objects that aren't fields in my database table?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

For example, say I'm storing customer account balance changes over time. I store the amount of the change in my table (the field is `amount`), as well the date of the change (`date`).

Say I have one change, and I'd like to get the amount of the previous change for that user (which is not a property of the object). If I were writing the SQL query by hand, I would do something like this:

```
SELECT *,
    (SELECT b1.amount
    FROM balanceHistory as b1
    WHERE b1.date < b0.date
    AND customer_id = 123
    ORDER BY B1.date
    LIMIT 1) as prev_balance
FROM balanceHistory as b0
WHERE customer_id = 123;
```

In Symfony, I could write a custom query and, once I have each account change, fetch that change's related previous change; but this is expensive as I'm iterating over many objects.

Can I add a new property, something like 'previousChange', but not add any ORM information, and not have it screw up any of the ORM stuff? If I can, once I do a manual join like this one, how do I access this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not really supported, since hydration of entities happens only on mapped fields.

What you are looking for is probably [Native SQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#examples), which allows you to run such complex subqueries by using the dialect supported by your DBMS vendor.

In Native SQL, you can add [scalar results](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#scalar-results) to your resultsets.
That way, you can still run your custom query, but have all the additional data you wanted in the resultset, along with your entities.

Also, consider that conceptually, such data does not belong to your entity, so keep it separate from your entities.

Comment: Interesting. In that case, where is the proper place to put a function that would return the full name of a customer, where the first name and last name are fields in the database? (I could do it in the template layer, but say it was a very complex function.)

Comment: That is indeed a view layer functionality, and should not live in your persistence layer if it is not based on persistence.

Comment: What about the example in my question? Supposing there were 80 balance change objects, and in my view layer I want to display each object's associated last change. The only way I can think of doing this in the view layer is via lazy loading, which would really slow things down. What's the correct thing to do in this case?

Comment: You could aggregate that into a smarter "Model" that wraps both the balance hystory entity and the result of the grouping. Something along the lines of `class BalanceViewModel { Balance $balance; int $previousBalance; }`

Comment: I think I understand. Then, in the view, I'd have access to my balance object via `model.balance.[property]` and to the other variable via `model.previousBalance`, correct?

Comment: @SamSelikoff yes, so basically that model is just a "smarter" balance, but the real entity is unaffected.